# Extract data out of a dataframe

Tags: r, bash

I'm quite new with programming and I have a question.
I have a file with multiple rows and i want to extract the rows that have a X and a Y for the same name. But my problem is that there are multipe X's and Y's for some names and i need to have at least 1 X and multiple Y or the other way around!

my data looks like this:

```
-   -   -   -   -   An.Pos  -   -   -   Name    -   - - - - 

1   678731  680107  2   8   X   1376    1   677193  685396  RP11-206L10.3   12  NA  NA  .    
1   1572876 1636342 2   4   X   63466   1   1590786 1594063 RP11-345P4.7    9   NA  NA  .    
1   1572876 1636342 2   4   Y   63466   1   1603429 1604850 RP11-345P4.7    9   NA  NA  .    
1   1572876 1636342 2   4   X   63466   1   1631369 1633249 MMP23A  9   NA  NA  .
```

What I want to get is:

```
1   1572876 1636342 2   4   X   63466   1   1590786 1594063 RP11-345P4.7    9   NA  NA  .    
1   1572876 1636342 2   4   Y   63466   1   1603429 1604850 RP11-345P4.7    9   NA  NA  .
```

But in my real data it can be that RP11-345P4.7 has more than two rows.
So wat i need is the names that have at least 1 X and 1 Y.

PS. I also dont know if it is easier to do it with R or Bash, or another language.

Comment: try to give a reproducible example. Here your column don't have a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, to first group by the `Name` column and then filter all rows that contain at least one X and one Y in the `An.Pos` Column.

If you use dplyr (and assuming that your dataframe is saved in `df`), it would look like:

```
dplyr::group_by(df, Name) %>%
 dplyr::filter(2==n_distinct(An.Pos)) %>%
 dplyr::ungroup()
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot!